# "\d" failed in jdbc program

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

In PostgreSQL, we can list tables in a database with the `\d` command in client terminal but it failed in a client JDBC program. Is it possible? Why and Why Not?

Comment: To elaborate on @a_horse_with_no_name's answer, all backslash commands are `psql` only, and are not understood server side. You can see what they do by running `psql -E`, but there's often a more portable or standard way to do it than how `psql` does it - eg via `information_schema` while `psql` will usually use `pg_catalog` instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger   What do you mean by "portable"? How one Postgres differentiates from another? Across OSs?

Comment: Portable between different SQL database systems, mostly, in case you need to run on MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. The more standard stuff you use the less porting hassle there is. In the case of `pg_catalog`, it changes from Pg major version to Pg major version too, whereas `information_schema` doesn't anywhere near as much (it's struture is set by the SQL standard). Using `information_schema` where possible can make upgrades easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d`  is  a `psql` command, not a SQL statement.

To get the tables available in the database you should use the JDBC API, such as [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Alternatively, you can run

```
select  table_schema, table_name
from information_schema.tables
```

To get a list of table names.

Answer (score 1):

select schemaname, relname

from pg_stat_user_tables

this will list all the user table,

information_schema.tables will list all user tables and the tables belongs to schema "information_schema and pg_catalog"