# In JDBC for PostgreSQL, can I execute commands of psql?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

When using a JDBC driver for PostgreSQL in a Java program, is it correct that I can only execute SQL commands?

Can I execute psql-specific commands, such as `\conninfo`, `\l` ...?

Does JDBC directly connect to PostgreSQL server, not to any client such as psql?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58312/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-database-from-within-postgresql

Comment: It seems that no, you can't do that from Postgres, but perhaps could do it in some other databases.  But, there might be functions available which you could call from a SQL query which would give you the information you want.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816657/what-is-jdbc-counterpart-of-postgres-connect-command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460479/d-failed-in-jdbc-program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PostgreSQL JDBC driver does not use `psql` at all. It is implemented in Java and does not even use the C client shared library `libpq`.

There is no way to use `psql` commands with JDBC.

If you start `psql` with the `-E` option, you can see the SQL commands that `psql` sends to the server during processing its commands. That might give you a clue how you can emulate `psql` functionality using JDBC.

Comment: Or better yet, use the standard JDBC API to get most of that info.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Thanks. What methods in JDBC API to get that info?

Comment: @Tim Check the documentation of the JDBC interface `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` and the PostgreSQL JDBC driver for information and look for equivalent functionality. There probably will not be a 100% equivalent for everything, but for most cases there will be something comparable.